# Python 2.7.5, getting sum of an array/ list, proper use of len and output result

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

Working on moving code from a flowchart tool to python, loaded an array with 3 student ages, and want to get the sum of the 3 ages, I'm new to python and want to know how it is you do this, I get an error running what I have, here is my code so far:

```
#g is my index, sample input was: 35,25,50 
st_age = [0]*3 
for g in range(0,3):
    st_age[g] = int(input("Enter student age "))

g = 1
sum = 0 
while g < len(st_age): #am I using this correctly? 
    sum = sum + st_age[g]
    g + g + 1

print sum #I get a zero this way.
```

thank you for the assist, arrays have been tricky so far.

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing g. `g + g + 1` shoudl read `g = g + 1`.

Also indices in python are 0-based, hence your starting value should be `g = 0`.

Also python has a neat builtin `sum`.

`print sum(st_age)`

So your fixed code could read:

```
st_age = [0]*3 
for g in range(3):
    st_age[g] = int(input("Enter student age "))

g = sum = 0 
while g < len(st_age): #am I using this correctly? 
    sum = sum + st_age[g]
    g += 1

print sum
```

Or with a list comprehension and builtin `sum`:

```
st_age = [int(input("Enter student age ")) for _ in range(3) ]
print (sum(st_age)) #Note extra parentheses
```

I put in the extra parentheses, so your code will run fine in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: (facepalm) I"m still working on reading what I write properly. I'm very new to coding.

Comment: I almost forgot about the zero based indicies, the flowchart tool starts at 1, good reminder!

Comment: @JuanB457 Normally, is you have in python something like `for x in range(len(something))` or `while g < len(something)` you should rethink your code. In almost all cases, there is a simpler way to do it. In python you almost never need to iterate over indices, and if you must, you can use `enumerate`. See the last code snippet of my answer.